# XRandR. What does suffix 'H' in the mode name mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, xrandr, kubuntu

XRandR. What does suffix **'H'** in the mode name mean?

I use cvt command to get modeline:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
```

Get modeline:

```
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

After that I create a new mode in XRandR with suffix **'H'** in the mode name
 ("1920x1080_60.00**H**"):

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00H"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

After that I add and set this mode for the display:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080_60.00H 
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00H
```

In the end it fixes overscan problem on my tv.
I couldn't find anywhere information of what **'H'** does and how it works.

Does anyone know where I can find information about this suffix **'H'**?

Answer (score 0):

`--newmode` takes two arguments: `name` and `mode`. The latter is a Xorg ModeLine, but the first one is just a name. You can put anything you want in there. The name is so unimportant that [xrandr(1)](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) doesn't even mention it:

> --newmode name mode
>
> New modelines can be added to the server and then associated with outputs. This option does the former. The mode is specified using the ModeLine syntax for xorg.conf: hdisp hsyncstart hsyncend htotal vdisp vsyncstart vsyncend vtotal flags. flags can be zero or more of +HSync, -HSync, +VSync, -VSync, Interlace, DoubleScan, CSync, +CSync, -CSync. Several tools permit to compute the usual modeline from a height, width, and refresh rate, for instance you can use cvt.

(To make sure, I just created a mode called "this is not important", and xrandr had no problem adding or displaying it.)